# DocFX No .NET API detected for project

Tags: .net, docfx

I used to be able to just build a `DocFX` page both locally and on `gh-pages`. But since recently,  I keep getting a warning message: `No .NET API detected for project`. This happens both locally and on `gh-pages`, even when I install a fresh `DocFX` according to the [Quick Start Guide](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/index.html) and call `docfx docfx.json --serve` on the default file.

Does anyone know what the issue is and how I might be able to solve it?

Comment: Do you have a [mre]? What .NET SDKs to you have installed?

Comment: On my local PC i have both .net 6.0.3 and 7.0.2. Whenever I install .NET in Github Actions, i use 7.0.x. Just following the Quick Start Guide with a fresh project already produces this error for me, but it also happens in other projects with custom setups.